# How can I return an XLSX response with NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm working with Nodejs/NestJs, and now I'm trying to generate an `xlsx` file (at this point, I'm not sure if my code is right), and now I want to send this file as the response, but I don't know how to perform it. I read about the `@Res` decorator, but I don't resources to attach a file on response.
Do you have any idea? Thanks :)

Service:

```js
downloadFile(file: number) {
  this.files
    .findOne({
      attributes: ['content'],
      where: { id: file },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const book: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(response.content, {
        type: 'base64',
      });
    
      return XLSX.writeFile(book, 'test.xlsx', { type: 'file' });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('some error: ', error);
    });
}
```

Controller:

```js
@Get('download/:file')
@Header('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data')
downloadFile(@Param('file') file: number, @Res() res: Response) {
  this.fileService.downloadFile(file)
}
```

Comment: Try returning the ```this.fileService.downloadFile(file)``` -> ```return this.fileService.downloadFile(file)```

Comment: I don't know what your `findOne` function is doing, but it looks like reading an XLSX file and piping the content. You then get this content and create a new `workbook` in memory, which you then write to the disk. That last part is probably unnecessary. It would be better if you send the created workbook (or the original) as the response. [Check this GIST to see how you could do that](https://gist.github.com/fuzunspm/5deac95ac7a552d977339df32bdc202e)